# How do I prove that the strong law of large numbers is equivalent to $P(∩_{n=1}^∞ ∪_{{k}\geq{n}}{|{\frac{1}{k}}S_k-p|\geq{ε}})=0$

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

I want to solve the following task:

Show that the strong law of large numbers statement is equivalent to the following statement:
For all ε>0: $$P(∩_{n=1}^∞∪_{{k}\geq{n}}{|{\frac{1}{k}}S_k-p|\geq{ε}})=0$$

The strong law of large numbers is:
$$P(ω\inΩ: \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_{n}(ω)}{n}=p)=1$$

I just thought about:

1. $$S_n(ω)=\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}X_i(ω)=X_1(ω)+X_2(ω)+...+X_n(ω)$$
2. $$P(X_i=1)=p$$
3. $${|{\frac{1}{k}}S_k-p|\geq{ε}}$$ $$\Leftrightarrow$$ $$-εk+pk≥S_{k}≥εk+pk$$

I think that's all I need to solve the task. Does anybody have an idea? Thank you:)

Comment: $(ω\inΩ: \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_{n}(ω)}{n}=p)$ is the complement of $(\cup_k∩_{n=1}^∞∪_{{k}\geq{n}}{|{\frac{1}{k}}S_k-p|\geq{\frac 1 k}})$.

Comment: I thought about it but why?

Comment: That proves the equivalence completely.

Comment: I got it. Thank you